# One to Many Relationship with extra fields in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I face a problem implementing some Database ERs in Laravel. The problem is present for both "1-1" and "1-N" relationships.

The example bellow is pretty straightforward I think.

We have a ***"Team"*** And a ***"Player"***

***One Team Has Many Players***. The problem comes in case I need to keep extra info for that relationship.

An example would be "***The Player Plays for that team from Date_1 to Date_2***".

In this example it seems that we need an extra table to keep this kind of info. As I know Laravel does not use pivot tables for "1-1" or "1-N".

So, how would we implement this case the Laravel way..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one. But I would ad one more table called player_records. With the following attributes

```
player_id
team_id. 
start_date
end_date
```

In each model I would have helper methods to get for example active players.

Here is the Team model.

```
class Team extends Model
{

    public function playerRecords() {
        return $this->hasMany(PlayerRecord::class);
    }

    public function activePlayers() {
        return $this->playerRecords()->where('start_at', '<=', Carbon::now())->where('ends_at', '>=', Carbon::now())->with('player')->get()->pluck('player');
    }
}
```

Here is the Player model

```
class Player extends Model
{

    public function playerRecords() {
        return $this->hasMany(PlayerRecord::class);
    }

}
```

And here is the PlayerRecord model

```
class PlayerRecord extends Model
{

    public function player() {
        return $this->hasMany(Player::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Edvard for answering. I can see your points. I have one question though. This way we make one extra query (which is not too much indeed!) each time we need the PlayerRecord. Is this the best way to go?

Comment: One extra query indeed. But I can't at the moment figure out a better solution.